# Php artisan migrate: access denied

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, composer-php

Hello I just recently started using Laravel and I can't seem to create a database table using migration. 
It gives me this error when I input php artisan migrate
[image]

Can't seem to find the answer to the problem, here is my .env:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:xsHVPf6IVsYHsTs71fbOxRgs86bW3B+M2FhhPh4bNro=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=MyDB
DB_USERNAME=AmielDB
DB_PASSWORD=root

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_KEY=
PUSHER_SECRET=
```

and here's my database.php:

```
'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '3306',
            'database' => 'MyDB',
            'username' => 'AmielDB',
            'password' => 'root',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

If you configure your database after run the laravel server then you have to restart your server i mean mysql and apache then try again. And are you sure your passowrd is root? Please ensure your Database, UserName & Password.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't interchanged username and password???

If u set .env after served(php artisan serve), you need to exit and serve again.

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note;

Sometimes you can forget you **web server** is **down** then you get the terrifying **"Access denied!"**.

Spent sometime other time having configured system wide access to PHP path but later realized I hadn't brought up the web server, Apache in my case.

Hope it helps someone!